Can I use a 1 GB RJ-45 connection on my router, with a 1 RJ45/Cat6 port?
I have a NETGEAR CM1000 cable modem. It's given me 5 good years of good service. However, after waiting several years for Comcast/Xfinity to come to my area, they have recently put in fiber optics throughout my neighborhood, so I'm thinking of upgrading to fiber Internet connectivity.
However, I prefer to buy my own device, rather than rent from Xfinity for years to come. I've searched for an Optical Network Terminal (ONT) by a company named StarTech.com. Specifically, StarTech.com IMC1GSFP. According to the specs I've found online, it has a port that would connect to my router, via RJ45/Cat6. I believe it would send data at a rate of 1 GB. My router is a Synology RT2600ac. Looking at the spec sheet I have for that, the WAN Port is a 1 GB RJ45. I want to know if the ONT would send data too fast for Synology router?

This won't work in the way presented: WAN uses modem communication protocols, not ethernet - even in modem+router combos, AFAIK the modem and router portions are kept separate from the other because modems and routers do not speak the same communication language, which is why modems are always required. A fiber modem would have an incoming fiber connection going to the modem and an ethernet connection out of the modem to a router's WAN port for firewalling and NAT. The IMC1GSFP is for LAN side connections, not WAN-side modem connections, even then it would need to be fiber to RG6, not ethernet

https://www.startech.com/en-us/networking-io/imc1gsfp "Overview" tab says it is 10/100/1000 Mbps.
The "Technical Specifications" tab says "Ethernet Gigabit"
These statements from the manufacturer look like the equipment ought to support Gigabit.  While I've heard of Cat6 or Cat5e or even Cat5 supporting Gigabit, I've also been taught that the superior Cat6a (or better, e.g. Cat8) is recommended for Gigabit.  And, of course, the remote device will need to provide Gigabit support in order for a 1000 Mbps connection to be established.
(This answer has been editing about 4-5 hours after it was initially posted, to add the following information...)

I want to know if the ONT would send data too fast for Synology router?

No.
They are rated at the same speed.  That is good enough.  This is not something you're likely going to be needing to worry about.
"But what", a person new to networking might ask, "if one device sends data too fast for another device?  Certainly there is some possibility that both devices don't go the exact same precise speed, right?"
I recognize that may sound like a pretty valid concern, so here is a bit of a lengthy answer diving into some surface-level details that may help explain a bit why, hopefully at least enough to put some minds at ease.
Computer networking technology is based on ideas that get standardized.  In this case, both devices are rated at 1 Gbps.  So if they create a standard 1 Gbps connection, that is a name for a standard for the speed they will attempt to communicate at.
I say "attempt", because there is some possibility that one or both might not be able to communicate that quickly.  There may be overhead in some of the protocols, like either TCP or UDP (part of "Layer 4" of the standard "OSI model"), IPv6 or IPv4 (part of "Layer 3" of the standard "OSI model"), and/or Ethernet or Wi-Fi (part of "Layer 2" of the standard "OSI model").
In addition to costing overhead, some of these protocols offer some form of traffic congestion control.  UDP not so much, but certainly TCP, Ethernet, and Wi-Fi.  So if a bunch of devices are connected to a common medium (e.g. a 100Mbps Ethernet hub) and both try talking at the same time, there may be ways to compensate for this, such as devices using the Ethernet protocol using Full Duplex to be able to communicate anyway, or devices noticing an Ethernet-based "collision" and that they need to re-transmit (using rules like Ethernet's randomized "back-off" period that helps the next attempt be more likely to work well).  The re-transmission helps to make sure the message gets delivered successfully, even though it might get delayed a bit.
Now, maybe one device is fast enough that in theory it could operate at 1067 Kbps (nearly 4.2% faster than 1024 Kbps = 1 Mbps).  But it won't communicate faster than 1024 Kbps because that is the fastest communication expected by the standardized speed that we call a 1 Mbps connection.  And maybe some device is actually slower than expected, and can only communicate at 998 Kbps and so can't even quite reach the expected speed (maybe due to some reason like being an Ethernet/USB adapter, and a USB hub causing some bandwidth limitations).  While that might technically violate the specification, it will probably get away with it, because protocols are used to make sure that communication works decently, and sometimes information can get re-transmitted so that it doesn't get lost/forgotten.  (I say "sometimes" because something like that is more likely to happen with some times of connections, like a TCP connection, rather than other types, like a UDP connection).
Modern software typically sits on top of a "software stack", so something like a web browser doesn't need to worry about Ethernet re-transmissions or TCP re-transmissions, or inter-network slowdowns caused by devices like firewalls or IDS ("intrusion detection systems").  In short, from the application's perspective, it mostly "just works".
A brief review indicates the "Synology RT2600ac" router can operate at a "Blazing-fast Wi-Fi with up to 2.53Gbps combined wireless bandwidth to supercharge your Internet experience."  So if the "Synology RT2600ac" router's Wi-Fi is operating at 2.53 Gbps(*), then in theory the router shouldn't be getting too overwhelmed by a 1 Gbps connection with the ONT.

(*) Of course, I highly doubt you'll be getting 2.53 Gbps of traffic.  Wi-Fi actually has a horrendous amount of overhead in perfect laboratory conditions without other airwaves affecting the air, and people don't actually live in environments with such "perfect" laboratory conditions, so it's not uncommon to struggle with some very significant overhead.
(Something like 30%-50% overhead is pretty common!  Just... don't trust advertised Wi-Fi speeds.  Don't even pretend to trust them.  They official speeds cited by the connection standards are definitely, without exception, way, way off from experienced reality.)


This answer assumes modems and routers speak the same communication language - they don't (it's why modems are always required and why routers can't be directly connected to an incoming WAN connection from the ISP). The OP wants to retain usage of an RG6 cable modem with a fiber connection by using a LAN-side SFP to ethernet converter - where would that ethernet connection then go after being converted from fiber, as it can't go into the ethernet port on the CM1000 since that's a WAN connection to a router - there are no incoming ethernet modem connections, it's DSL, RG6, or fiber

I see no indication that there are plans for ongoing use of the "NETGEAR CM1000 cable modem".  It seems like the question asker has a Synology RT2600ac, which the person seems to want to keep using (presumably rather than upgrading beyond 802.11ac), and so wishes to connect to an Optical Network Terminal (ONT) like one from StarTech.com IMC1GSFP which converts the fiber-optic to Ethernet.  So the RT2600ac's WAN port would connect to the IMC1GSFP (which converts between the Ethernet and fiber), instead of the RT2600ac's WAN port connecting to the "cable"-technology CM1000.

"This answer assumes modems and routers speak the same communication language"... No.  I prsume the modems speak whatever language they want, and the Gigabit Ethernet Cat6 RJ45 port communicates with the same Ethernet "language" as any other standard Ethernet.  I'm simply presuming that StarTech.com made a useful device which communicates with the standards that StarTech.com published there would be compatibility with.  The whole deal about whatever languge is used by the DSL/RG6/fiber/etc. would be handled by the other side of the IMCGSFP device, and not be affecting the Ethernet side.

@TOOGAM thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I don't understand it all; I'm a developer, but networking isn't in my wheelhouse. However, I understand enough of what you've said to make be convinced I can get the StarTech.com IMC1GSFP and connect it to my router. Seems like that's what I have to concern myself with.

@TOOGAM The same as a router is not a modem and modems are not routers, a LAN side SFP to Ethernet converter is not a modem, and in order to communicate with the ISP, regardless of connection type [DSL, RG6, Fiber], a modem is required. Modems don't use the same communication protocols as routers - all the IMC1GSFP does is convert the signal from SFP to Ethernet, similar to how a SPDIF converter converts to digital coax [RG6]. With no modem, there will be no communication with the ISP. All the OP will be doing by purchasing the IMC1GSFP is wasting their money since it isn't a modem

@Rod It's not a modem, it's a LAN-side SFP to Ethernet converter only and is for incorporating Ethernet connections into a LAN-side fiber network - all it does is convert SFP signals to Ethernet signals, nothing more. When you have a LAN-side fiber network, patch panels may not have Ethernet ports, which is where the IMC1GSFP comes in, allowing the connection of Ethernet devices to a LAN-side fiber network, not for modem connections to an ISP - please see my comment directly above this for that explanation

Rod, you may want to consider @JW0914's comments.  I can tell you that I've worked at an ISP where we supplied Internet to a location (using some wireless equipment that didn't involve a piece of equipment that we called a "modem"), and our on-location equipment the provided direct connectivity to various customers, and so we really didn't use a "modem" at all for that type of connection.  On the other hand, we did use a "modem" for some other types of connections to other locations.

The significance of my prior comment is that a modem is absolutely required for some types of connections.  So while I've been reluctant to agree that a modem definitely is needed, I don't wish to suggest that such a device isn't ever required.  In some cases, a device that is often called a "modem" definitely is absolutely required to be able to use the service.  I do expect that a service provider should be able to tell you about any such requirement (if you ask them).

@JW0914 : Thank you for your persistence. I didn't feel like the question really focused on the role of a modem, so my asnwer focused on the StarTech.com IMC1GSFP to Synology RT2600ac connection that the question seemed focused on. However, I do admit that the topic of a required modem might be extremely relevant and not be something that should be overlooked, and problems could happen if people have expectations and aren't giving enough attention focused on that portion of the networking setup. Your persistence to caution about mis-info, & help prevent problems, is recognized and appreciated

@JW0914 thank you for being persistent. You're correct, my understanding is incomplete. I thought that the StarTech.com IMC1GSFP would be what Xfinity would connect to. Now, given what you've said, I realize I am wrong. So, what, regardless of what it's called, do I need to get so Xfinity can connect to that? And do I even need the  StarTech.com IMC1GSFP at all?

@TOOGAM, oh the service provider is more than willing to provide me with what I need, so long as I rent it from them. That isn't what I want to do.

@Rod You'd likely need a fiber modem with SFP in (or whatever incoming connection it is) and WAN Ethernet out that has the throughput specs required, as well as the requisite number of down and up channels (I'm assuming that portion of the modem doesn't change with fiber, but I may be wrong - with a 500mbit/s upload & download cable broadband service, it's not one channel up and one channel down that does 500mbit/s each, but usually x amount of channels at ~40mbit/s per channel that are aggregated, however that may be different with fiber)

@JW0914 I'm reaching out to Xfinity to find out what I need. They seem reluctant to tell me and want me to rent a modem from them. If they aren't willing to tell me, I'll stay with what I've got. Anyway, here's hoping.

I've learned that Xfnity isn't interested in me owning the devices I would need, to make using fiber Internet possible. They insist that I must rent their devices, which I don't want to do. So, thank you everyone for your help. It was great, but at this point I can't take advantage of it.
